# Apply same function for many datatable in one page. How can i call it?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have five data tables. I want to add paginations for all tables. I wrote a method with five ids. but it's not working. please help me.

```js
$("#myTable1 ,#myTable2, #myTable3,#myTable4, #myTable5").DataTable({
  "dom": 'ftp',
  drawCallback: function(settings) {
    var pagination = $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate');
    pagination.toggle(this.api().page.info().pages > 1)
  },
  "language": {
    "emptyTable": "No records found"
  }
});
```

Comment: give a class for all the datatables and access it using `.` operator as `$(".classname").DataTable({`});`

Comment: HI @NijinKoderi can i call using ids

Comment: can you add html content along with question? @harendra

Comment: <table class="table table-custom" id="myTable1">

Comment: `$("table[id^='myTable']").DataTable({ });` try this using `attributeStartsWith selector`

Comment: @Harendra use of a common class is the best option you can do. you are already having a class 'table' and you can use like `$(".table").DataTable({});`

Comment: Thank you very much @NijinKoderi. This code working. $("table[id^='myTable']").DataTable({ });

Comment: @harendra  happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Comment: Hi @NijinKoderi, If you can add an answer I can mark it accepted.so please add a answer that code.

Comment: @harendra Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using `attributeStartsWith selector` as

```
$("table[id^='myTable']").DataTable({ });
```